# How do I trigger a jQuery code while using the jQuery validation library?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using [jQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) library to validate both password inputs to have the same value. My code is written below.

```
$(".woocommerce-ResetPassword").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        password_2: {
            equalTo: "#password_1"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        password_2: "<div class='woocommerce-password-strength bad'>Passwords do not match</div>"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    return true;
    }
});
```

I want to execute a `jQuery` code to add a `class` to an `element` when the notification of `password_2` appears.

I want to modify this part of the code by adding a jQuery script inside the **messages: {}** but the code below does not work. You can see that I added `$(".woocommerce-form-row--last").addClass("notif-triggered");`

```
messages: {
    password_2: "<div class='woocommerce-password-strength bad'>Passwords do not match</div>"
    $(".woocommerce-form-row--last").addClass("notif-triggered");
},
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is this resolved now ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell us, but I'll assume you're using the validation library linked [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler).

You should be able to add functionality within an `invalidHandler`, e.g. something think this:

```
$(".woocommerce-ResetPassword").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        password_2: {
            equalTo: "#password_1"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        password_2: "<div class='woocommerce-password-strength bad'>Passwords do not match</div>"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       $(".woocommerce-form-row--last").removeClass("notif-triggered");
       return true;
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
       $(".woocommerce-form-row--last").addClass("notif-triggered");
    }
});
```